# Create Tabular format data based on values in 2 variables using C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 variables with different values. Say 
State: In Dev, In Test, Done, In Dev, In Dev, In Test, In Dev, Done and corresponding StateReason values are: Dev in progress, Test in progress, Handover Complete, Dev in progress, Dev in progress, Ready for QA, Completed

I need to create a table in this format.

```
State/State Reason  In Dev  In Test Done    Total
Dev in progress     3       0       0       3
Test in progress    0       1       0       1
Handover Complete   0       0       1       1
Ready for QA        1       0       0       1
Completed           0       0       1       1
                                    Total   7
```

Is there any built in function that I can use to create in the required format please? like LINQ or Distinct. I created in the required format but written too many lines of code. Wanted to check if there is a simpler way in creating a required format. Code I have written to get the metrics count is as below but to format it, I have written good amount of code.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dUse = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int k=0; k<mcnt.Length;k++) { if(dUse.ContainsKey(mcnt[k])) { dUse[mcnt[k]] = dUse[mcnt[k]] + 1; } else { dUse.Add(mcnt[k], 1); } } foreach(var item in dUse) { Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Value); }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Using Lists and Dictionary I was able to get the data in a tabular format.